# Jmeter hangs when using KERBEROS

Tags: windows, jmeter, kerberos

This occurs when running Jmeter with multiple threads (users). With single user, the issue does not happen.

OS: Windows 10

Edit:
I mean by "hangs" that Jmeter waits a response from the server forever which should be already responded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by setting HTTP client implementation to Java [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj1v6.png).
Java implementation does not use connection pool and I think that's the reason for it to be resolved (just a wild guess though).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "hangs"? If you're using GUI for running your "multiple threads" - please don't as GUI mode is only for tests development and debugging, when it comes to execution you should be [using JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)

If it still "hangs" in the non-GUI mode:

1. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Make sure that JMeter doesn't lack CPU, RAM, doesn't do frequent garbage collection, etc. If it does - you will need to go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
3. Take a [thread dump](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/19170) and see which and where the thread(s) got stuck and increase logging for this components

Comment: Jmeter doesn't recognize a server response which should be already responded and waiting it forever. This is not related to memory or CPU. Thanks anyway.